# Homebrew package manager and sudo

Tags: macos, homebrew

I didn't see that they had a forum, and I tried to Google why homebrew doesn't prefer to use the sudo command, but most of the posts I found were like, "Why would you want to?", or "Don't do it", which didn't really answer the question I was trying to find an answer to.

It's confusing for me since I come from a linux environment, and just recently joined the mac ecosystem.  With Ubuntu-like and Arch distros you typically use sudo to install applications to be used by the system and make changes to system directories that is typically not governed by a single user of your machine.  This made sense to me, since even Administrator access is needed to perform installs on Windows, which I'm also somewhat familiar with.  These system directories are usually owned by root.

One of the first prompts was to change the owner of /usr/local to my user.  I eventually did it, and it's been fine, but to this day, I'm still wondering why they do it this way since I'm not the only user of this machine.  I understand that it makes it group writable, but it still seems weird to me that one standard user modifies a system directory owned by another standard user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Homebrew users are on their personal machine and as thus the shared directory issue doesn’t apply. When you’re sharing a machine with multiple users you can install it somewhere else if you prefer, e.g. in `~/brew`.

You can still use `sudo` with Homebrew if the `brew` executable is owned by `root`. However it’s completely unsupported.